# How to combine two AWK commands?

Tags: linux, awk

I have two command line with AWK which works perfectly:

```
awk 'NR >=2 {for (i=7;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~ /^-/) sum1 += $i; print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,sum1, ; sum1 = 0}' test.txt

awk 'NR >=2 {for (i=7;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~! /^-/) sum += $i; print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,sum, sum/192 ; sum = 0}' test.txt
```

I want to combine these two commands to one command so I would be able to get sum and sum1 and I want to print them both! and if posible use an equation!

something like this:

```
awk 'NR >=2 {for (i=7;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~! /^-/) sum += $i; {for (i=7;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~ /^-/) sum1 += $i ; print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,sum,sum1, sum/(192 +(sum1*2)) ; sum = 0 ; sum1 = 0}' test.txt
```

or

```
awk 'NR >=2 {for (i=7;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~! /^-/) sum += $i && {for (i=7;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~ /^-/) sum1 += $i ; print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,sum,sum1, sum/(192 +(sum1*2)) ; sum = 0 ; sum1 = 0}' test.txt
```

but I get this error:

> awk: cmd. line:1:
>   ^ unexpected newline or end of string

in case it helps my file is something like this:

```
probeset_id submitted_id chr snp_pos alleleA alleleB 562_201 562_202 562_203 562_204 562_205 562_206 562_207 562_208 562_209 562_210 562_211 562_212 562_213 562_214 562_215 562_216 562_217 562_218 562_219 562_220 562_221 562_222 562_223 562_224 562_225 562_226 562_227 562_228 562_229 562_230 562_231 562_232 562_233 562_234 562_235 562_236 562_237 562_238 562_239 562_240 562_241 562_242 562_243 562_244 562_245 562_246 562_247 562_248 562_249 562_250 562_251 562_252 562_253 562_254 562_255 562_256 562_257 562_258 562_259 562_260 562_261 562_262 562_263 562_264 562_265 562_266 562_267 562_268 562_269 562_270 562_271 562_272 562_273 562_274 562_275 562_276 562_277 562_278 562_279 562_280 562_281 562_283 562_284 562_285 562_289 562_291 562_292 562_294 562_295 562_296 562_400 562_401 562_402 562_403 562_404 562_405 
AX-75448119 Chr1_41908741 1 41908741 T C 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
AX-75448118 Chr1_41908545 1 41908545 T C 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 2 2 0 1 1 1 2 -1 1 2 0 0 2 1 1 0 1 0 1 2 1 0 0 1 2 2 1 2 2 0 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 1 0 0 0 1 2 2 2 2 0
```

and I want the result to be like this

```
AX-75448119 Chr1_41908741 1 41908741 T C 13 0 0.067
AX-75448118 Chr1_41908545 1 41908545 T C 98 -1 0.515
```

Comment: It can be done by bash. What is the output of the first two `awk` command?

Comment: what do you mean?? the format?

Comment: After you run each of `awk 'NR >=2 {for (i=7;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~ /^-/) sum1 += $i; print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,sum1, ; sum1 = 0}' test.txt` command, what is the output you get?

Comment: This is incorrect: `$i ~! /^-/` -- the operator is `!~`. However it would be more clear to the viewer to use numeric operations: `$i < 0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the nicely formatted version with explanation:

```
awk '
NR>1{
    #Initialize the variables to 0 for every iteration

    sum=0;
    sum1=0;

    #Loop from 7th column till the end

    for(i=7;i<=NF;i++) 
    {

    #Test if the value in that column is greater than zero

        if($i>0)   
        {    

    #If test returns true, add value to variable sum

            sum+=$i; 
        }
        else 
        {

    #If test returns false, add value to variable sum1

            sum1+=$i; 
        }
     }

    #Loop again through the column 1-6

        for(i=1;i<7;i++) 

    #Print the values of those columns

            printf("%s ",$i); 

    #Print variables and function

            printf("%d %d %f\n",sum,sum1,sum/(192 + (sum1*2))) 
}' test.txt
```

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk '
NR>1{
    sum=0;                                                
    sum1=0; 
    for(i=7;i<=NF;i++) 
    {          
        if($i>0) 
        {                                 
            sum+=$i; 
        }                  
        else 
        {
            sum1+=$i;                                         
        }
     }                 
        for(i=1;i<7;i++) 
            printf("%s ",$i);
            printf("%d %d %f\n",sum,sum1,sum/(192 + (sum1*2)))
}' test.txt
AX-75448119 Chr1_41908741 1 41908741 T C 13 0 0.067708
AX-75448118 Chr1_41908545 1 41908545 T C 98 -1 0.515789
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick (and avoids multiple iterations).

```
$awk 'BEGIN{sum=0;sum1=0} NR >=2 {for (i=7;i<=NF;i++) if ($i !~ /^-/) sum += $i; else if ($i ~ /^-/) sum1 += $i; print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,sum, sum1,sum/(192 +(sum1*2)) ; sum=0;sum1=0}' test.txt

AX-75448119 Chr1_41908741 1 41908741 T C  13 0.0677083
AX-75448118 Chr1_41908545 1 41908545 T C -1 98 0.515789
```